# React routing with names instead of ids

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React application, I'd like to be able to navigate to sub-pages of my domain using the `name` property of my entity, rather than its `id`.

For example:

**Now:** `https://.../companies/1`

**Desired:** `https://.../companies/company-name`

The problem that I am trying to deal with is that with the first approach, I can easily fetch the company object from my backend, since I can simply use the passed `id` for that. However, for the second case, that is not anymore possible. Of course, I could create a method that fetches the company by `name` instead of `id` but that is neither elegant nor completely correct, considering that for some company names (e.g. those with spaces), the url parameter will be encoded, thus will not match with the original one.

Is there a smart way to achieve the desired outcome without storing some kind of mapping for ALL the potential company-urls in my Redux store? (e.g. `company1 -> 1`, `company2 -> 2`)

Comment: You can still pass the id property through the react router state

Comment: history.push({pathname: '/companies/company-name',
  state: { id: <company-id> }})

Comment: Sure, but that won't work when you are copy-pasting the url with the name to a new tab.

Comment: Yes, you are right all data would be lost, even the redux store data. Maybe store the data in the local storage will help you.

Comment: If the user copy and paste the url to a new tab, you can redirect to the page where he can select the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is most definitely possible, but there is more work on the backend than the client (React).

If your route is defined as `/companies/:id` the `:id` can be anything. It can be `1234`, it can be `h3h3h3` and it can be `amazon-company`.

What `:id` marks is the name of the param which will hold your value.

For example:

`https://.../companies/amazon`

```
const { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const { id } = useParams(); // id will be 'amazon'
```

or, alternatively:

`https://.../companies/1`

```
const { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const { id } = useParams(); // id will be '1'
```

Now you have a specific problem with your idea, what about duplicate names? There are definitely more than 1 "Amazon" in the world, maybe not LLC, maybe D.o.o, maybe GMBH, but the point is, all of those would use the same name in your system.

What you want to do is incorporate some form of a `slug` in your backend.

When you're creating a Company Model in your backend, add something like this in the controller:

```
// CreateCompany.js

const Schema = {
  slug: req.body.title + Math.random(...)
}
...
```

This will create a unique slug for the company name, such as `amazon-235h35`. You can learn more about proper slug usages on google, this is just an example ;)

And then instead of routing by `companies/${company.id}` you would do `companies/${company.slug}`

Does this make anything clearer?

Comment: Good point! So you basically now have slugs that are unique and url-ready-encoded so you can use these to fetch your unique companies. I think for the slug I'll just go with lowercasing, removing special chars and replacing spaces with dashes, since I don't have duplicate names. But thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

May be you need this:

Use Link to dynamically generate a list of routes.

Use : to indicate url params, :id in this case

Use the match object passed as props to the rendered route component to access  the url params. this.props.match.params.id

```
<BrowserRouter> 
      /* Links */ 
      {heroes.map(hero => (<Link to={'heroes/' + hero.id} />)} 

      /* Component */ 
     <Route path="heroes/:id" component={Hero} /> 
 </BrowserRouter>

class Hero extends Component { 
 render() { 
   return ( 
       <div>
          {this.props.match.params.id} 
      </div> 
   );
 } }
```

Comment: Yes. I thought you were asking something simpler. Sorry man. Antonio's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @antonio's answer - you can also put both in your URL separately (the slug + the name). This is the model Amazon uses.

For instance: these two URLs go to the same place, because the label of "Madden 24" is just to be easily readable by us, Amazon doesn't care (they're using B0C6NDYH6Z to look up the content):

- [https://www.amazon.com/Madden-NFL-24-PlayStation-5/dp/B0C6NDYH6Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C6NDYH6Z)
- [https://www.amazon.com/CompletelyMeaningless/dp/B0C6NDYH6Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C6NDYH6Z)